# How to determine Panorama item index when selected panorama item is changed

Tags: wpf, silverlight, xaml, windows-phone-8, panorama-control

I am building a panorama which displays images through binding. I need to find index of panorama item whenever the current item changes. But the **SELECTIONCHANGED event is not firing in case when data is retrieved through binding.** Can you please suggest some other way. Thanx in advance

**XAML Code**

```XAML
<phone:Panorama x:Name="HeaderPanorama"
    ItemsSource="{Binding PanoramaImages}"
    Width="550" Margin="-10,-255,0,-140"
    SelectionChanged="HeaderPanorama_SelectionChanged_1">
    <phone:Panorama.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Image Source="{Binding}" Margin="-10"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </phone:Panorama.ItemTemplate>
</phone:Panorama>
```

**CodeBehind**

```C#
private void HeaderPanorama_SelectionChanged_1(
        object sender,
        SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (this.DataContext != null && this.DataContext is HomeViewModel)
    {
        ((HomeViewModel)this.DataContext).PanoramaItemIndex =
                HeaderPanorama.SelectedIndex;
    }
}
```

**ViewModel Code**

```C#
public HomeViewModel()
{
    RequestHomeData();
    PanoramaImages = new List<string>();
    PanoramaImages.Add("/Assets/n.png");
    PanoramaImages.Add("/Assets/n.png");
    PanoramaImages.Add("/Assets/n.png");
    PanoramaImages.Add("/Assets/n.png");
}

private List<string> _panoramaImages;
public List<string> PanoramaImages
{
    get { return _panoramaImages; }
    set
    {
        _panoramaImages = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged("PanoramaImages");
    }
}

private int _panoramaItemIndex;
public int PanoramaItemIndex
{
    get { return _panoramaItemIndex; }
    set
    {
        _panoramaItemIndex = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged("PanoramaItemIndex");
    }
}
```

Comment: This question might help you:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14260701/windows-phone-8-panorama-selectionchanged-databinding/22731993